# How to confidently and concretely state that a problem has no analytical solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equality

$f(\sigma, X) = g(\sigma, Y)$

where $\sigma$ is some parameter and $X$ and $Y$ are generic sets of other parameters/variables, where generally $X \neq Y$.

Say I would like to solve for $\sigma$ in terms of the other relevant variables and parameters, ultimately desiring a solution of the form

$\sigma = h(Z)$

where $Z$ is a set of parameters/variables that may be a subset or identical to $X\cup Y$.

Now, how do I state with concreteness that $\sigma$ has no analytical solution? That is, no such $h(Z)$ exists without including non-elementary functions which need be calculated numerically. For my specific problem, I known that no analytical solution is available simply for the reason that I tried with WolframAlpha to no avail. How do I communicate that no solution exists without having to state that I have made infinite attempts and none of them worked?

Comment: In general, it is very hard to prove that a specified form is _not_ possible. The theories that deal with such problems are typically research level (e.g., differential galois theory). I would simply state that the standard CAS packages (Mathematica, Maple, Macsyma) are unable to solve analytically, so it's "likely" that no analytical solution is possible (or at least is not known to be possible).

Comment: I don't think there is a general criterion for that. But you might perhaps be interested in differential Galois theory and the Liouville's theorem for indefinite integrals in elementary terms.